# jQuery combobox() limit the result based on entered text

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am using this dropdown as combobox

```
<div class="ui-widget">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ToID, ViewBag.ToRetlID as SelectList, "Select RETL", new { @id = "DdlRetl", @class = "combobox" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ToID)
            </div>



$(function () {
    $("#DdlRetl").combobox();
});
```

Currently it loads all users from db which makes the page slow.
Is there any way I could get only the first 10 results and then when I scroll get the rest.

Or can I use an autocomplete for this task?

Please let me know if there is another easy and better solutions for this.

Comment: why dont you use auto-suggest textbox ?

Comment: autocomplete functionality will do http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/dropdown_list_auto_complete.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jQuery comboBox loads its whole records at one time, it does not affect on performance by limiting records based on entered text.

To improve performance use jQuery autocomplete where you can find this feature of limiting the result's count based on entered text.